# Given an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ and another $m \times m$ matrix $B$ where $m <n$, how to compare the largest eigenvalue of $A$ and $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given an $n \times n$ irreducible matrix $A$ and another $m \times m$ irreducible matrix $B$ where $m <n$, is there any formula for comparing the largest eigenvalue of $A$ and $B$ ?
I mean one bound is $\|A\|+\|B\|$. I am looking for anything better.

Comment: The eigenvalues of either matrix could be anything.  For example, A could be the 0 matrix (with all eigenvalues equal to 0) and B could be a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues of arbitrary size (or vice versa).

Comment: @NicNic8: I mean one bound is $\|A\|+\|B\|$. I am looking for anything better.

Comment: Much too vague of a question here.

Comment: We can "generalize the question" (to make obvious all comments): >> Given two matrices, $A$ and $B$ on two different real vector spaces, together with a bounded operator $C$ on the Hilbert space $l^2(\Bbb Z)$, how to compare the largest eigenvalue of $A$ and/or $B$ and/or $C$ with $\|A\|+\|B\|+\|C\|$?

Comment: Which matrix norm you are using ? Spectral norm, I assume ?